# Delete Applications shown in Launchpad

Tags: macos, finder, applications, migration

I recently got a new MacBook Pro and used migration assistant to transfer files over from my old MacBook Pro via an intermediary external hard drive. After completing the transfer, my new Macbook’s Launchpad shows several Applications that were not shown in my old macbook’s Launchpad, and none of the applications are listed in either the old macbook’s or  macbook’s Applications folders.

I would like the applications deleted (which I’m assuming would then remove their icons from Launchpad, and their data from my machine).

I’m guessing they are somehow hidden applications, but I can’t find where, even with hidden files displayed, and their names don’t appear when searched in Finder. Also, most of them, when I try to open them from Launchpad, then displays a message saying something to the effect of “couldn’t open this program” with the options to report, ignore, retry opening. The few that don’t display this message never open, don’t appear in my dock, and aren’t Force-Quit-able.

I’m currently running macOS 12 Monterey on my nee MacBook Pro.

Comment: You can delete apps from Launchpad much like on iOS, by holding a long click on an app. Then you'll get an X next to each icon, and they will all wobble. However, I'd suggest it's better to make sure they aren't anywhere on your disk.

Comment: @benwiggy that only works for apps from the mac app store